# Is there a way to create an Other option with Javascript that causes a textbox to appear

Tags: javascript, html, cs50

Tried to create an Others option in a drop down menu, which by doing so, activates a textbox to type in.
However, my current method of doing this causes the remaining options to be invisible when clicked, and the textbox does not appear when the Others option is clicked.

```js
function disappear(val) {
  var textbox = document.getElementById('issue');
  if (val == 'other') {
    textbox.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    textbox.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="issue" id="issue" onchange='disappear(this.value)'>
  <option disabled selected></option>
  <option value="bug">Bug</option>
  <option value="lacking">Lack of Use</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="textbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are selecting the wrong element

`var textbox=document.getElementById('textbox');`

```js
function disappear(val){
          var textbox=document.getElementById('textbox');
          if(val=='other'){
            textbox.style.display='block';
          }
          else{
            textbox.style.display='none';
          }
        }
```

```css
#textbox{
width:90px;
height:60px;
background-color:red;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<select name="issue" id="issue" onchange='disappear(this.value)'>
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="bug">Bug</option>
          <option value="lacking">Lack of Use</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="textbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's how you must do it:

```
 var textbox=document.getElementById('textbox');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, it seemed to me that everything was obvious here, but I will consider

Comment: For illustration, observe that the answer by UmairFarooq posted two minutes after yours got three upvotes and is the accepted answer, while yours got no upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yes, yes, I was in a hurry, I always answer differently, there are more detailed answers

Answer (score 0):

You're really close! The only thing left is to change the id in the `document.getElementById` to the correct element and add the input field with the styling.

```js
function disappear(val) {
  var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
  if (val == 'other') {
    textbox.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    textbox.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="issue" id="issue" onchange='disappear(this.value)'>
  <option disabled selected></option>
  <option value="bug">Bug</option>
  <option value="lacking">Lack of Use</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input id="textbox" type="text" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: oops, thanks for the advice, working better now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Should your `textbox` actually be a `textarea` element? Note: if it's meant to be a `div` it won't appear on the page (unless you style it) because its content is empty.
2. Use CSS to initialise the textbox display to `none`.
3. In the function you've picked up the `select` element with your query, and not the `textbox` element which is why the options are disappearing when you set the display to `none`. Maybe add an additional check to see if the style is set to `block` before you set the display to `none`.

```js
function disappear(val) {
  var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
  if (val == 'other') {
    textbox.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    if (textbox.style.display === 'block') {
      textbox.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#textbox { display: none; }
```

```html
<select name="issue" id="issue" onchange='disappear(this.value)'>
  <option disabled selected></option>
  <option value="bug">Bug</option>
  <option value="lacking">Lack of Use</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
```

Comment: nice touch. textarea was the helpful feature I needed. thank you